# Convert VB.Net Linq statement to C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq, silverlight-4.0

I am just starting to learn C# 5 (.net 4.5) and was in the process of converting an existing VB.Net Silverlight 4 business application over but I am struggling to convert the below Vb.Net Domain Service method.

It is not compiling giving me "Invalid expression term 'return'" and "Expected contectual keywork 'by'" exceptions.

Can you please give me some guidance.

**Model**

[image]

**VB**

```
Public Function GetBusinessUnits() As IQueryable(Of BusinessUnit)

    Dim var1 = From cat In ObjectContext.CabSystemsModelCategories
                Group cat By cat.BUID Into Group
                Select BUID

    Return ObjectContext.BusinessUnits.Include("CabSystemsModelCategories").
                        Where(Function(w) var1.Contains(w.ID)).
                        OrderBy(Function(o) o.ID)

End Function
```

**C# so far (Not Working)**

```
public IQueryable<BusinessUnit> GetBusinessUnits()
{

        object var1 = from cat in ObjectContext.CabSystemsModelCategories
                    group cat by cat.BUID into group

        return ObjectContext.BusinessUnits.Include("CabSystemsModelCategories").
            Where((w) => var1.Contains(w.ID)).
            OrderBy((o) => o.ID);

}
```

**EDIT**

Changing the code to include the select gives an additional exception "Invalid expression term 'select'"

```
var result = from cat in ObjectContext.CabSystemsModelCategories
                    group cat by cat.BUID into group select BUID
```

Comment: You need to state *What isn't working*! Is it a compilation error or a runtime error? "not working" will get you nothing but close votes to be honest.

Comment: and you're missing your select in the var1 the C# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Here is the working method.

```
public IQueryable<BusinessUnit> GetBusinessUnits()
{
    var includedBU = from cat in ObjectContext.CabSystemsModelCategories
                                group cat by cat.BUID into grouping
                                select grouping.Key;

    return ObjectContext.BusinessUnits.Include("CabSystemsModelCategories").
            Where((w) => includedBU.Contains(w.ID)).
            OrderBy((o) => o.ID);

}
```

Comment: Recommmend setting this as the answer (even if you are answering your own question. The "keys" were to change "Group" to something else (VB only allows Group whereas C# requires anything other than group). Also, using the "Key" property inserted by C# which you have to do explicitly in VB.

Comment: Will do when the site allows me (2 days)

Answer (score 1):

You are grouping into "group" which is a reserved word in C#. Try this:

```
var result = from cat
             in ObjectContext.CabSystemsModelCategories
             group cat by cat.BUID
             into grouping
             select grouping;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It now gives me a "The name 'BUID' does not exist in the current context" compile error

Comment: Changed `select BUID` to `select cat.BUID`. Does it work this way?

Comment: Nope. Compile error changes to "The name 'cat' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: In C#, `group` is not a normal reserved keyword, it's contextual and reserved only in LINQ queries.

Comment: If the code is meant to just collect all unique BUIDs, selecting the grouping should work. Not sure about VB syntax...

Answer (score 0):

In your C# example you never `Select BUID` when setting up `var1` otherwise they're equivalent.

What version of C# are you using? You should probably declare `var1` as `var` instead of `Object`

Comment: or IQueryable. But since he uses LINQ I guess he uses 3.5+ so var should work.